# Workflow being executed multiple times after editing an item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have 5 workflows all automatically starting when an item is changed. However, these workflows keep on executing even after editing the item.

[image]

Comment: Do any of the workflows modify the item?

Comment: yes the workflows modify the items except for the create new item and

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same when I had one of my workflows write data to a column on the list.  I set conditions on some of the workflows to prevent from executing multiple times.

Comment: Yes the workflow writes data to the column. There is also a condition before the task to write data to the column

Comment: Every time the workflow edits the item, the workflow runs again... because you told it to run every time the item is changed.

Comment: but i only edited it one time. upon saving, the workflows keep on executing. Is there a way to stop it and only execute upon one edit?

Comment: You edit it, then the workflow edits it again. It doesn't matter who edits it, even if it's the workflow, it will cause the workflow to run again.

Comment: When should it run? What are you changing that's different from what the workflow is changing? Can you check at the beginning of the workflow to see if your value is already set, and stop the workflow if it is?

Comment: it should only run after I edit the item. the workflow sets value to a field that is not visible in the infopath form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41880/discussion-between-ehj-daria-and-erin-l).

Answer (score 0):

Create a yes/no column named `Run Workflow`, hidden from users. Write a rule in InfoPath on submit that sets that field to Yes. For every workflow that should run only when a user edits, add at the beginning. `If Run Workflow equals No` then `Stop workflow`, `Else set Run Workflow to No`.

This will allow the workflows to run one time. They'll still start again every time a workflow edits an item, but it will immediately stop because the "Run Workflow" flag is set to No.

The reason you had to add a pause to avoid a coercion error is because you have 4 workflows updating the item all at the same time, so one workflow locks the item for editing, and the other workflows can't update it.  I would combine all workflows that change fields into one workflow, probably with parallel steps.

Comment: thanks erin! my problem with pausing the workflow is that sometimes, it takes more than 5 minutes to execute. Longest is 30 mins. I even made the pause for only 1 second by using number variable

Comment: It sounds like your workflow timer job isn't running correctly. The default is set to run every 5 minutes, but if you have large numbers of workflows running and/or paused at one time, it can slow the workflow engine down. I can't really help you there, but researching workflow engine performance might get you somewhere.